# Using PHP itself to parse/find function calls

Tags: php, regex, parsing

I'm wondering if it's possible to use PHP's parser to parse files and search/find a given function call.

For example, I want to know from which files the function `eval` is called. I could use `find` with `-exec` and some regex, but that returns a lot of false positives, and it also returns commented code.

My question is: can I use somehow PHP's own parser to search in files and say if a given function/reserved word is used in that file?

Comment: Why not just open it with `fopen()` and do a search for your keyword ?

Comment: Not with regex. There is infinite count of options to call some function named `$function` in PHP. `call_user_func` or `$function()` are most easiest from them

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran I'm not really sure I understand what you suggest. Can you elaborate a little bit further your idea?

Comment: Using [Nikic's PHP parser](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser) would be a  better approach

Comment: @AlmaDo Those are corner cases. I'm be more than happy if I could get at least the direct calls. Also, if I'm using PHP's parser it should be possible (somehow) to let it know that there is actually a call to what I'm looking for.

Comment: You should then define what is 'direct' function call and what's the difference of 'indirect'

Comment: @AlmaDo Direct call: A stright call (as in ```my_function($arg1, $arg2);     Indirect call: Anything you can imagine to call a function  without using a direct call, aka, evals, cast magic, call_user_func and pretty much everything else that belongs to PHP's reflection capabilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use PHP's internal tokenizer to find direct calls to eval:

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents('test.php');
$tokens = token_get_all($data);

foreach($tokens as $token){
        if($token[0]==T_EVAL){
                echo "Eval found on line: ".$token[2]."\n";
        }
}
```

If you want to look for other things you can change the constant from T_EVAL to one of the constants specified here: [Tokens](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tokens.php)